# Local IP address of Android device connected via Ethernet

Tags: 7.0-nougat, usb-on-the-go

I have an Android Tablet with **Android 7.0** connected to my network via an OTG **RJ45 Ethernet** connector.

I know how to get local IP address when connected via WiFi, but not via Ethernet.

Any idea on how to do that (eventually with an app compatible with Nougat)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the information you are looking for with the `ifconfig` command. On your android device install a terminal emulator app and open a local connection.

> The ifconfig is a system administration utility in Unix-like operating systems for network interface configuration.

- connect and setup your Ethernet connection.
- Open the terminal app.
- Enter the command `ifconfig` into the terminal.
- scroll down and look for eth0 or close to that.
- You should be able to find the ip address there.

Comment: Indeed. I was trying a terminal emulator but it was crashing. It worked nicely with `Terminal Emulator for Android` (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm). Thanks